# Most effective way to redraw image

Tags: c#, gdi+

I'm making a very simple 2D game. Unfortunately I ran into an issue with refresh rate when I add images. I use Invalidate on a timer tick which works fine until I change `DrawRectangle` to `DrawImage`. With just 27 objects on the screen `Paint` refresh rate drops from stable 64 to 39 on average. Images that I use are only 2-3kb so they shouldn't cause an issue. Please help me to understand this. Why and How does it happen? What causes and issues and how to fix it?

Perfectly fine:

```
foreach (Ground _en in game.blocks)
{
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Green,_en.rec);
}
```

Causes frame drop:

```
foreach (Ground _en in game.blocks)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(Image.FromFile(_en.background), _en.rec);
}
```

Comment: Are you using Windows Forms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're loading the file into memory from the hard disk each time you call .FromFile(). Store the image in your Ground class on instantiation (or whenever, just not when you are calling it in Draw()) and this should be fixed.

Comment: +1 Moreover don't forget (outside this simple case) that GDI+ is terribly slow, you may consider to draw (at least) images using GDI or, if it's not just an exercise, to drop GDI+ and to move to DirectX (or drop GDI+ and WinForms all together and move to WPF)...

Comment: GDI+ is faster than WPF. The main trick is to use the premultiplied ARGB bitmap format.